# FileNotFoundException with Universal Image Loader

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

This question is about this popular Android library, **Universal Image Loader for Android**: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

1. I made sure WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is added.
2. I enabled both memory and disk cache
3. I used UnlimitedDiscCache for disk cache
4. I'm building against Android 2.2 SDK. The exception is found when I'm testing the app on a Android 4.1.2 Nexus S device.
5. For most of my images, the loading is smooth and fine. However, for certain images, I always get the same exception. Below is an example.

Image URL: http://i10.topit.me/l046/10046137034b1c0db0.jpg

Back trace:

```
01-14 00:24:42.125: 

ERROR/ImageLoader(1671): http://i10.topit.me/l046/10046137034b1c0db0.jpg

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://i10.topit.me/l046/10046137034b1c0db0.jpg

at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)

at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.URLConnectionImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(URLConnectionImageDownloader.java:40)

at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.ImageDownloader.getStream(ImageDownloader.java:27)

at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.saveImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:296)

at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:204)

at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:128)

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
```

Please help.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but those images might need a proxy to be accessed and I remember there were issues with proxies in API level 8.

Comment: Not likely. All the images are hosted on the same server. Most of them can be downloaded on my testing Android device without a problem

Comment: I get a 404 visiting that page (which would cause file not found), although the 404 page is just an image located at http://img.topit.me/404.jpg that says (love)it.me.

Comment: And now I don't. Use a better image server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Follow up:

I finally solved my problem without changing one line of server code. What I did is replacing the default **URLConnectionImageDownloader** with **HttpClientImageDownloader**

Code sample:

```
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Turn off stale checking. Our connections break all the time anyway,
        // and it's not worth it to pay the penalty of checking every time.
        HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
        // Default connection and socket timeout of 10 seconds. Tweak to taste.
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10 * 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10 * 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);

        // Don't handle redirects -- return them to the caller. Our code
        // often wants to re-POST after a redirect, which we must do ourselves.
        HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
        // Set the specified user agent and register standard protocols.
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "some_randome_user_agent");
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

        ClientConnectionManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);


        ImageLoaderConfiguration config =
                new ImageLoaderConfiguration
                        .Builder(MainActivity.sharedMainActivity.getApplicationContext())
                        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                        .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                        .threadPoolSize(1)
                        .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                        .imageDownloader(new HttpClientImageDownloader(new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params)))
                        .build();
```

:)

Comment: Am I unlucky !!! getting --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null, using HttpClientImageDownloader

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's helps me. Just one thing in code, need context in last line: `.imageDownloader(new HttpClientImageDownloader(msContext, new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params)))`

Comment: @DiWu Sorry mate for query im facing same problem. But im using latest version of UIML. In which class you done this changes ?
URLConnectionImageDownloader with HttpClientImageDownloader
Name of the package and class ?

Comment: 03-09 18:12:59.535: E/ImageLoader(9878): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.dakabo.dk/images/phocagallery/Levende_vaerksted/dsc09327.jpg%20
03-09 18:12:59.535: E/ImageLoader(9878):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:194)
03-09 18:12:59.535: E/ImageLoader(9878):  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:124)

Comment: Not able to implement this. What is HttpClientImageDownloader class.Pls help

Comment: What is HttpClientImageDownloader class?

Comment: I cannot implement this HttpClientImageDownloader, how to make it works?

Comment: Nostra removed the class from the library. See: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/commit/dcf8aea684b6385a72e67f4552119178a0204d1d

Answer (score 4):

Look for implementation of `libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream()`

```
 @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (!doInput) {
            throw new ProtocolException("This protocol does not support input");
        }

        retrieveResponse();

        /*
         * if the requested file does not exist, throw an exception formerly the
         * Error page from the server was returned if the requested file was
         * text/html this has changed to return FileNotFoundException for all
         * file types
         */
        if (responseCode >= HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(url.toString());
        }

        if (responseBodyIn == null) {
            throw new IOException("No response body exists; responseCode=" + responseCode);
        }

        return responseBodyIn;
    }
```

According to this it can throw FileNotFoundException even if server error occurs or unauthorized.

I have not found value of HTTP_BAD_REQUEST but it's always was 400. Source code link 
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/org/apache/harmony/luni/internal/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java.htm

Comment: And if you go to the address you will find there is such file yourself: http://i10.topit.me/l046/10046137034b1c0db0.jpg

Comment: Yes, I've just did it. Seems that something strange happens. But stack trace definitely says that file was not found

Comment: Sometimes server really responds 404 (actually it constantly respond 404 after several successful responds). So this is not a UIL's problem.

Comment: is there any solution to it

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is to disable logging at all by `L.disableLogging()`. Or change the sources according to your needs.
Source: [nostra13's answer for this problem](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/558)

Answer (score 0):

This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you may tune some of them, or you can create default configuration by `ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);` method.

```
 public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {

    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context);
    config.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
    config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();
    config.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator());
    config.diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024); // 50 MiB
    config.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO);
    config.writeDebugLogs(); // Remove for release app

    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
}
```

I hope this helps anyone.