# FileNotFound Exception in UniversalImageLoader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using universalimageloader.jar for showing images in my application.
But for certain images I am getting filenotfound exception. I searched on google and came across this answer. [FileNotFoundException with Universal Image Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305765/filenotfoundexception-with-universal-image-loader) 
But I am not able to implement this solution provided. Kindly helps!!
Thanks

Comment: What are you not able to implement this solution, which is already provided?

Comment: Actually I am not able to write HttpClientImageLoader class

Comment: what do you mean by not able to write HttpClientImageLoader class?

Comment: I am not able to get what HttpClientImageLoader class is..

Comment: I tried writing the class but ImageDownloader class to which it should be extended is not available in the jar